# android get any item in gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I have a gridview with x buttons, x rows and 4 columns.  I am trying to delete or make not clickable a button or even a row..a row might be better..I want this deletion to take place when I start the application.  I only want the last four items in the gridview to be clickable, then when one of them is clicked I want the items 5,6,7,8 to only be clickable.  I am having trouble with this because I do not understand how to get a certain item(s) in the gridview so I can set them to not clickable.  I will show you code so far:

Mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView text;
private GridView gridView;
private TextView timerValue;
private Boolean firstclick = false;
private long startTime = 0L;
private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
private Button buttonclicked;
Random r = new Random();
//private int[] rannumbers_array = new int[32];
private int[] shuffle_array = new int[4];
private String[] items = new String[8];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedback);
    timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);
    timerValue.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int ranval = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if ( (i % 4) == 0)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
            {
                shuffle_array[x] = 0;
            }
            do {
                ranval = r.nextInt(100);
            } while((ranval % 2) != 0);
        }
        else
        {
            do {
                ranval = r.nextInt(100);
            } while((ranval % 2) == 0); 
        }
        shuffle_array[j] = ranval;
        j++;
        if(j >= 4)
        {
            j = 0;
            shuffle(shuffle_array);
            do {
               items[k] = Integer.toString(shuffle_array[j]);
               k++;
               j++;
            } while(k <= i);
            j = 0;
        }
        //rannumbers_array[i] = r.nextInt(100);
        //items[i] = Integer.toString(rannumbers_array[i]);
    }
    k = 0;




    gridView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.myGridView);
    final CustomGridAdapter gridAdapter = new CustomGridAdapter(MainActivity.this, items);
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
    buttonclicked = gridAdapter.getbutton();
    gridView.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            gridView.setSelection(gridView.getCount() - 1);
        }
    });
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(!firstclick)
            {
               customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
               firstclick = true;
            }
            gridAdapter.getItem(51); //can I make this not clickable or not visible?
            //view.invalidate();
```

my CustomGridAdapter:

```
public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private String[] items;
private Button button;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomGridAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, null);
    }
    button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item);
    button.setHeight(175);
    button.setText(items[position]);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public Button getbutton()
{
    return button;
}
```

}

cell.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/grid_item"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:maxHeight="175dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:text="05"
android:textSize="25sp"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"/>
```

activitymain.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timerValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:text="@string/timerVal"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/myGridView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/feedback"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Does anyone know how I can access any item or group of items in the gridview?

Comment: Why don't you disable buttons in CustomGridAdapter.getView method?
i.e. if (position > 10)... or any other condition button.setEnabled(false)

Comment: Good idea, thanks!  How do the positions work in relation to the items (or in my case buttons)?

Comment: GridView does not inflate all elements in an adapter. It inflates only visible items and then when the user scrolls the widget it inflates items which become visible. So "position" in getView method is the position of an item in adapter, it does not related to position in grid view.